# How to extract the cycle lengths from a permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

I want to input: `Cycles[{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {7,8}}]` and get something like: `{3,3,2}`, that is, a list of the cycle lengths in the permutation.

Comment: `Length /@ Cycles[{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {7, 8}}][[1]]`, or as a function `f[x_] := Length /@ x[[1]]` where you can just input `f[Cycles[{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {7, 8}}]]`

Comment: OK !  Thank You!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two similar ways using the operator form of [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) available since V10.0:

```
Cycles[{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {7, 8}}] /. Cycles -> Map[Length]
Map[Length] @@ Cycles[{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {7, 8}}]
(*  {3, 3, 2}  *)
```

Comment: Also `Cycles[{{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {7, 8}}] // Apply[Map[Length]]` to use the operator form of `Apply` as well.